# Data type mismatch error in string query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to run the following query from Access's Create Query:

```
SELECT table.string, function(table.string) AS afterFix
INTO checkFix
FROM table
WHERE function(table.string)<>table.string;
```

I get the following error when trying to run the function: **Data type mismatch in criteria expression.**

`table.string` is defined as **short text** and it's field size is 50. some might be NULL, `function` is my vba function that returns a **string**. 
this is the function:

```
Public Function illegalCharEliminate(ByVal fieldName As String) As String
    Dim field As String
    field = fieldName
    If (IsNull(field)) Then
        GoTo catchNulls
    End If
    For i = 1 To 128        'goes through all illegal ascii and removes illegal chars
        Select Case i
            Case 1 To 44, 47, 58 To 59, 60 To 64, 91, 93, 123 To 125, 127
                 field = Replace(field, Chr(i), Empty)
           End Select
    Next i
catchNulls:
    illegalCharEliminate = field
End Function
```

I tried Cast and Convert sql functions:

```
WHERE function(table.string)<>(Cast(table.string as string))
```

but get this error" **Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression function(table.string)...** I saw some answers for this problem in vba, but I really do not want to use vba for this query. **NOTICE:** If there are no problems with my syntax, then the reason is probably because the table.string column has nulls. if so, how to fix this?

Comment: Don't know if it will solve it, but your query runs on `table`, so your criterium must be the other way around: `WHERE table.string <> function(table.string)`

Comment: Can you show the code for `function`?

Comment: Shouldn't your WHERE clause be function(table.string) and not function(string)?

Comment: @Duston Yeah, sorry. fixed that now.

Comment: @andre451 I changed it around, though I don't see how it makes any difference. Still get the same error, obviously.

Comment: @Hambone  The function gets the table.string, changes/deletes some characters in it, doesn't change nulls, and returns table.string as string type (which means that if table.string is a null, it will return a null, I think.) Why does the code for the function matter?

Comment: I was wondering if it wasn't handling the nulls properly...  can you post the code for function?

Comment: @Hambone I'm adding the function to the question. Hope you can solve this.

Comment: Two final questions...  is your table really named `table` and your field really named `string`?  Also, where you have `function` up there, I assume in your actual query, you called out the function `illegalCharEliminate` and didn't actually say `function`?

Comment: @Hambone Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned these. Of course my table is **not** named `table`, nor is my `string` column named that. My function **is** actually `illegalCharEliminate` and when I added it to the code I left it's real name so that what it does would be apparent. Thank you so much for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your assessment that the null is the problem was correct.  The function fails when you give it a null value because a null is not a string (it's not anything).  I think this fix might address your issue:

```
SELECT
  table.string,
  illegalCharEliminate(iif(isnull(table.string), "", table.string)) AS afterFix
FROM [table]
WHERE
  illegalCharEliminate(iif(isnull(table.string), "", table.string)) <> table.string;
```

In essence, this converts null values to an empty string.

Comment: thank you so much. This worked perfectly. I didn't know how to do conditional statements in access beforehand, thanks!